# How to show SUM() value in T-SQL with condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I am trying to solve third problem from this site https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT.

**3.)Give the total GDP of Africa:**

Given relation to solve this:

```
name         continent   area     population   gdp  
Afghanistan  Asia        652230   25500100     20343000000
Albania      Europe      28748    2831741      12960000000
Algeria      Africa      2381741  37100000     188681000000
Andorra      Europe      468      78115        3712000000
Angola       Africa      1246700  20609294     100990000000
...
```

I wrote this:

```
SELECT SUM(gdp)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent = 'Africa'
```

It gives me basically 2 sums(Africa and world).

```
SUM(gdp)
69762111000000
1811788000000
```

How to show only sum of *gdp* of Africa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the where clause:

```
SELECT SUM(gdp) FROM world WHERE continent = 'Africa'
```

This way you will takie only results from Africa to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(gdp)
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Africa'
```